# Unity VR How to focus eyes correctly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am making an Android app for Unity, using my own VR engine. It is small, and I have got looking around working perfectly. The only problem I am experiencing is where I cannot get my eyes to focus on the objects in front of them. I get double vision where my left eye sees objects too far to the left, and right eye to the right. I have tried pointing the eye cameras slightly inwards and moving them based on a raycast to find out where they are looking.

I am guessing it could be something to do with pointing the eyes outwards, my rig - nintendo labo headset with android phone inside [ making do with what I've got ;) ] - unfortunately the phone and lenses don't quite line up but this doesn't seem to affect one of my other projects, or perhaps I need to distort my camera in a special way.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Honestly, I have no idea! Some help from an expert or anyone who is slightly clued up in the subject would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I literally just need to point the cameras out rather than in